# How to use regex on string within a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, switch-statement

I have an if else statement to match a string with vowels and consonants which works fine. I would like to tidy it up with a switch statement however using match() does not work as a case. what am i missing?

if else //returns vowels: 1, consonants: 3

```
function getCount(words) {
  var v,
      c;
    if (words === '' || words === ' ') { 
      v=0;
      c=0;
    } else if(words.match(/[aeiou]/gi)) {
        v = words.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
        c = words.replace(/\s|\W/g, '').split("").length - v;
    } else {
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
    return {
      vowels: v,
      consonants: c
    };
}

getCount('test');
```

switch //returns vowels: 0, consonants: 0

```
function getCount(words) {
  var v,
      c;
    switch(words) {
      case words.match(/[aeiou]/gi):
        v = words.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
        c = words.replace(/\s|\W/g, '').split("").length - v;
        console.log("true");
        break;
      case '':
      case ' ':
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
        break;
      default:
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
    return {
      vowels: v,
      consonants: c
    };
}

getCount('test');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Code goes here

function getCount(words) {
  var v,
      c;
    switch(true) {
      case ( words.match(/[aeiou]/gi) !=null ):
        v = words.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
        c = words.replace(/\s|\W/g, '').split("").length - v;
        console.log("true");
        break;
      case (words==''):
      case (words==' '):
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
        break;
      default:
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
    return {
      vowels: v,
      consonants: c
    };
}

console.log(getCount('test'));
```

Comment: Explanation maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement needs to evaluate an expression and compare the result to the value of each case statement.

```
function getCount(words) {
  var v,
      c;
    switch(words.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length > 0) {
      case true:
        v = words.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
        c = words.replace(/\s|\W/g, '').split("").length - v;
        console.log("true");
        break;
      default:
        v = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
    return {
      vowels: v,
      consonants: c
    };
}

getCount('test');
```